# android application: Pick image from gallery then drag and drop the selected image

Tags: android

this is my code. this code is for picking an image from the gallery but then i need to drag and           drop that selected image. can u help me to do the code?

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class Looks extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private static int LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS = 1;

    private Button button;
    private ImageView image;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_looks);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.selectImageBtn);
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override 
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
            image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));

            cursor.close();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(i, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);
    }
}
```

Comment: When the user has selected an image the Gallery app closes and you can determine String imagePath in onActivityResult. So at that moment you have only a path to an image on file. You have no visible image. So where would you drag from?

Comment: i need to drag and drop image that have been selected from the gallery. the one that already picked from the gallery using this code. do we only need visible image to do the drag and drop?

Comment: `do we only need visible image to do the drag`. Well not 'only'. You need a visible image in order to be able to drag it. Or not? Well you have no visible image on that moment. Right?

Comment: But i do not understand your scenario. Why should there be drag and drop after picking? Please explain. You could as well first determine where the picked image had to drop or let the picking be followed by the user clicking the drop place. Please tell what you want to achieve and why.

Comment: im trying to do a virtual wardrobe where the apps can take a picture of our clothes and then we pick them back from the gallery to do the mix and match part.

Comment: Sorry but this information does not help as it is not to the point.

Answer (score 0):

I May not give a code.

But right direction to do this is to implement is using two fragments as follows:

Activity to activity Dragging animation can be simulated but it isn't possible in real and simulation isn't smooth.

1. Implement a fragment with button click.
2. On Click create a Dialog Fragment with Custom Image Picker.
3. On Click Image in Gallery, Hideother images with animation.
4. Make sure that imageview belongs to Activity so that can be dragged between fragments.
5. Animate imageview till it reaches holder of other fragment.
6. On Action Even Up if there is container, set image to imageView Container.

Comment: can u give the code? im quite new using android. i've watch lots of tutorial already. just this last part im stuck.

Comment: Please try above mentioned steps and post your code if you have any issues, we are here to debug it.